# "Today" vs "for today."

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

When to use the former and when to use the latter? For example here:

> You're only a slave (for) today. Don't worry.

Should there be an for? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you are trying to say. This question might be lacking a little context.

But generally one would use *today* when referring to the actual day in contrast to using *for today* when talking about something in connection with that day. See [preposition for](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/for).

Examples:

- "I will be working 8 hours *today*."
- "8 hours should be enough *for today*."

Comment: The sentence means: You are only going to be a slave for today, so don't worry. It'll pass soon.

Comment: Then 'for' would be the correct choice here.

Comment: Although I believe it wouldn't be gramatically wrong to only say "a slave today,", but using 'for' would be more precise.