# Is "A meeting is already arranged today" correct or should it be "arranged FOR today" or "arranged ON today"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-choice, time-words

My team is looking for a supervisor for our research project and we are currently in contact with one lecturer who asked us for a meeting today to confirm things. Problem is another lecturer contacted us and asked for a meeting today.

I want to reply back saying we already have a meeting arranged today. What is the correct way to say it?  Another meeting is already arranged "for today", "on today" or just "today"?

Comment: "We are all scheduled today" or "Today is booked." It is clumsy, and not diplomatic, to refer to your other candidates. That's your own business, and you have the right to be discreet.

Comment: While I agree that you should probably not explain why you cannot meet today "for today" would be correct if you did want to.

Comment: "for today" is less ambiguous: "we arranged a meeting today" could mean "we arranged a meeting today for a future date". But it's a bit pedantic (or neurotic) to be worried about that sort of thing. "We already have a meeting today" is another way of saying you're booked up.

Comment: Preposition deletion is a complex area. Looking solely at grammaticality (ie ignoring the pragmatics of what sounds most hearer-friendly) 'A meeting is already arranged/scheduled for today' is impeccable while 'A meeting is already arranged/scheduled today' sound a lot less idiomatic than say 'A meeting is already taking place today'.

Comment: In, say, *The meeting room is booked [for] today*, it doesn't seem to make any difference to the meaning whether we include the preposition or not. But if your boss says *You are not paid [for] today*, there's no doubt ***that*** makes a difference (or at least *could* make a difference).

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate) [“Today” vs “for today.”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/159427/9161) [I have applied for leave of absence today/ for today](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/224665/9161)

Comment: You could reply with something like "We are unable to see you [on date or today] due to other committments. Could you come on [another date]?"

Comment: Thank you all for the support. It seems "for today" could be used and is the answer to my question.